# Classic ASP use of "SameSite" on cookies

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

We're using Classic ASP to construct our cookies via Response.Cookies( "***CookieName***" ). How would we go about setting "SameSite" to none?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149155/force-all-cookies-setting-to-secure-in-classic-asp-vbscript this should help, it's code I wrote for setting custom cookies. SameSite settings is an option (none by default).

Comment: Thanks Adam. So essentially the only option is to use Response.AddHeader to create the cookie?

Comment: Classic ASP is 20 years old, `Response.Cookies` is quite limited, but `Response.AddHeader` gives you full control over the response header content.

Comment: Understood, it is just potentially a fairly lengthy re-write in the system I have adopted. Is there any way to edit the cookie after created with Response.Cookies to set SameSite or no go?

Comment: You can use web.config to add it automatically, but I don't have the code for that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (you need the URLRewrite module installed). You also need to be using the https protocol (`SameSite` only works if `Secure` is also included, and you can't include `Secure` without using the https protocol). `HttpOnly` should always be used too, but if you have some JavaScript code on your site that needs to read cookies, `HttpOnly` will prevent that.

You also might need to add "HTTP_COOKIE" to the "allowed server variables" in IIS under URLRewrite. But I think that's just for reading incoming cookies.

EDIT: Tried and tested, works perfectly.

Note: If you're already using `Response.Cookies("CookieName").Secure = True`, it will add `Secure` to the response header value twice (unless you remove `Secure` from the action rewrite value), being included twice shouldn't be an issue, but some browsers can be fussy with stuff like that, especially Chrome as Google continues to role out more and more updates with stricter cookies rules.

The `httpProtocol > customHeaders` section is completely optional, but it will add more security to your site.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="SameSite rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="(.*)=(.*)" negate="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}={R:2}; SameSite=None; HttpOnly; Secure" />
            </rule>     
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin" />
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam this does the trick, however I was hoping for an option to do this within my ASP code so that I could add some additional logic to check for system related settings in the DB. I'm now also discovering iOS doesn't support this and by setting this it will break iOS. This does not seem like a well thought out update by Google?? And also why wouldn't they allow some sort of 'whitelist' rather than forcing everyone to disable it all together